# Worksheet name from cell and filename functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I am trying to get the name of each worksheet in a workbook in the A1 cell of each worksheet.  I am using the following equation.

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),(FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1),(LEN(CELL("filename"))-(FIND("]",CELL("filename")))))
```

This seems to work but once I save the file every worksheet then has name of the worksheet that was active when I save the file rather than the correct name of the worksheet.   Is there a way around this or a better way to dynamically read the worksheet name?
THanks.

Comment: Is `filename` a defined name for a cell?  if so, you only have one (Excel won't let you create more than one, and you don't want multiples anyway.) Create different names for the cells on the other worksheets and then rewrite your formula.

Comment: filename is a set info_type for the CELL function that returns the fullpath and filename and worksheet name, I thought.   Defining the name of the cell will defeat the intended purpose of being to change the worksheet name at the tab and then having it automatically change in the A1 cell.

Answer (score 1):

For each formula, replace:

```
CELL("filename")
```

with:

```
CELL("filename",A1)
```

everywhere:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),(FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1),(LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-(FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)))))
```

Typically I:

1. first save the file
2. install the "name" formulas
3. re-save the file